# Joomla/K2 Listing K2 categories in a module parameter

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

Is it possible to list K2 categories in a module parameter using something like the default Joomla category field type?

```
<field name="mycategories" type="category" extension="com_content" multiple="true" label="Category" description="" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ZWhat happens if you change the extension value to `com_k2` ?

Comment: It shows a blank list (I've 3 categories for testing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from K2 content Module:

```
<fieldset name="basic" addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_k2/elements/">
    ...
    <field name="category_id" type="categoriesmultiple" default="" label="K2_SELECT_ONE_OR_MORE_CATEGORIES" description="K2_SELECT_ONE_ORE_MORE_CATEGORIES_FOR_WHICH_YOU_WANT_TO_FILTER_AN_ITEMS_LIST_SELECT_NONE_TO_FETCH_ITEMS_FROM_ALL_CATEGORIES"/>
    ....
</fieldset>
```